# Difference between System.Object.GetType and System.Type.GetType

Tags: c#

Is there any difference between `System.Object.GetType()` and `System.Type.GetType()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is ..

Read about [System.Object.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [System.Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I had posted that it inherits, I hadn't considered the overloaded methods though.  +1 for you. ^^

Comment: @Smudge202: More than that, why bother your self explaining while you can just pointing :D ..

Comment: when do we use typeof() operator

Comment: @Raghav55: I guess you use typeof() when you need to get the type from a class itself, not its instances.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Type` is derived from `System.Object`. As such it inherits the parameterless instance method `GetType()` from `System.Object`. It will give you the type of the subclass of `Type` you got. And that's largely useless.

The static `Type.GetType(string)` function and it's overloads are something different entirely, despite having the same name. They get you the type with a specific name.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.GetType()` gets the type of the current instance in which case it calls the `Type.GetType` for self.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Object.GetType()` - Gets the Type of the current instance.

E.g:

```
var s ="sdf".GetType() // Gets System.String
```

`System.Type.GetType()`   - Gets a Type object that represents the specified type

```
 Type type = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```